# How to encode variable number of arguments with `abi.encodePacked`

Tags: uniswap, abiencoderv2

I'm trying to use the UniswapV3 Router to execute a `Multihop` Swap which accepts the path as an encoded combination of token addresses.
Documentation: `https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/swaps/multihop-swaps`

From the documentation, for a swap from DAI to WETH via USDC the encoded path is:
`abi.encodePacked(DAI, poolFee, USDC, poolFee, WETH9)`

Now I want to generate this encoded path dynamically from a `address[] _path` array containing the token addresses and a `poolFees` array containing the pool fees. (which is one element shorter than `path`).

I would like to know how best to achieve this.

What I currently have tried is this:

```
function _encodePathV3(address[] memory _path, uint24[] memory _fees) internal view returns (bytes memory path) {
        path = abi.encodePacked(_path[0]);
        for(uint i = 1; i < _fees.length; i++){
            path = abi.encodePacked(path, _fees[i], _path[i+1]);
        }
    }
```

However this does not seem to work since it results in the following exception from the Uniswap Router, which I believe is connected to the malformed encoded path.

`Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'slice_outOfBounds'`

I'm using solidity 0.6.10 with `experimental ABIEncoderV2`

Answer (score 0):

The starting index of the loop was mistakenly set to `1`.
Changing it to `for(uint i = 0; i < _fees.length; i++)` fixed it.